# Necessary steps to build an iOS flutter app release version without App Store

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in Flutter.

I am familiar with the ways to build a flutter app for windows and for android as an apk file.

Furthermore, I have been looking at the process for an iOS release but most steps seem to be mandatory in order to release a build version to the App Store.

My goal is just to build a file to test it on mobile devices without releasing it to the App Store. Therefore my question is : what are the minimal steps to accomplish in order to obtain a iOS built version (use of Xcode, etc...) ?

Or put in other words : what steps of the folloing link should I follow and which ones to ignore ? https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios

I know the topic has been tackled many times but there are still some aspects which are not clear to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you just trying to build it and run it locally on a simulator?

Comment: I think you can use Testflight for this. Do not ignore anything until Testflight.

Comment: Yes indeed : basically, just like a windows app .exe file that I can run in any windows device using a usb key, I would like to run a iOS app on a mobile device for testing purpose.